# How can i Write a program that will read in a number and then print out a triangle of #s using nested loops?

Tags: python-3.x

Heres the code of the program.

```
def go( num ):  
    print(" ")


go( 1 ) 
go( 2 ) 
go( 3 )
go( 4 ) 
go( 9 )
go( 12 )
```

Now i am really having trouble understanding how to wrtie it so it goes through the list.
This is the code ive done so far

```
> def go( num ):
>     row = 0 
for i in range(row + 1):          
    for j in range(i):`       
        print(i, end=" ")

print("*")


   

go( 1 )
go( 2 ) 
go( 3 ) 
go( 4 ) 
go( 9 ) 
go( 12 )
```

I am currently getting a
"builtins.NameError: name 'row' is not defined" error,anything would help.
Also yeah i am kind of rushing this

Comment: I did,i just didint happen to see it was on the same line im sorry man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this

```py
def go(num):
    for i in range(num+1):
        for j in range(i):
            print(i, end=" ")
        print("")

go(2)
1 
2 2 

go(9)
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```